# Opacity on images in slider

Tags: image, slider, opacity

It's my first post on stackoverflow, and I hope, I would help to someone, and vice versa :D. What's my problem? I created image slider with kenburn effect. There are 3 images in slider. I want when image shown, it would be "normal image", and after some time, for example, after 2 seconds, image becomes darker, and some text would appear on image. I want it looks something like on this website **https://beslagicinterijer.eu/**
I hope You understand me. Thanks in advance.

```css
@keyframes opacity {
   0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0.3; }
}

.ws_images {
 animation: opacity 6s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="ws_images"><ul>
  <li><img src="data1/images/img1.jpg" alt="img1" title="img1" id="wows1_0"></li>
  <li><img src="data1/images/img2.jpg" alt="img2" title="img2" id="wows1_1"></li>
  <li><img src="data1/images/img3.jpg" alt="img3" title="img3" id="wows1_2"></li>
 </ul></div>
```